# Retag request: SQL Server tags on SF

Tags: support, retag-request

Should the SF tag `[sqlserver]` be retagged to be the same as SO tag `[sql-server]`?

As a DBA I use both sites, but often find myself typing the wrong thing!

---

**Edit (Jon):** Here's what currently needs cleaning up. I'd take care of these but I don't have enough rep.

`[sqlservermanagementstudio]` (44) --> `[sql-server-management-stu]` (to match SO)
`[sqlserveragent]` (15) --> `[sql-server-agent]`
`[sqlserver2008]` (2) --> `[sql-server-2008]`
`[sqlserver2005]` (5) --> `[sql-server-2005]`
`[sqlserver2000]` (4) --> `[sql-server-2000]`
`[sqlserver-reporting-servi]` (4) --> `[reporting-services]`
`[sql-server-reporting-serv]` (1) --> `[reporting-services]`
`[reportingservices]` (11) --> `[reporting-services]`
`[sqlserverprofiler]` (3) --> `[sql-server-profiler]`
`[sql-profiler]` (2) --> `[sql-server-profiler]`
`[sqlserverce]` (2) --> `[sql-server-ce]`
`[sqlserver-7]` (1) --> `[sql-server-7]`

On SO, there is `[reporting-services]`, as well as SQL Server version-specific tags (i.e., `[reporting-services2005]`), but there are less than 100 total questions on SF on that topic (and they'd need hand-separating), so I say leave it.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds reasonable enough. I imagine it would be best practices for all the tags across the systems to try and follow the same standard conventions (hyphens separating words, etc.).

This should be something fairly easy for a mod to go and switch up using the tools available.

Answer (score 2):

I also find this quite annoying. especially then threads get moved from stackoverflow To serverfault & they have sql-server tag.
Should i take it upon myself to re-tag all the existing sqlserver questions to sql-server ?

Answer (score 2):

Bump.

Every day more questions get created with the sqlserver tag, instead of sql-server. Is there any way of blacklisting over-used incorrect tags?

(speaking of which, latest offense is [here https://serverfault.com/questions/57722/how-long-can-a-mirrored-fail-over-partner-be-offline-before-a-full-backup-is-requ](https://serverfault.com/questions/57722/how-long-can-a-mirrored-fail-over-partner-be-offline-before-a-full-backup-is-requ)), asked by someone in this very topic...

Comment: I guess that's the problem - 'sqlserver' tag on SF has become more prevalent, and similarly on SO for 'sql-server'.  Difficult to start to use one over the other, unless a mod can re-tag first

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as part of the [RG sponsorship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-does-rg-mean) all the SF **sqlserver** tags have been updated to the SO **sql-server** standard. Time to update my ignore list.