# Please merge SQL Server Profiler related tags and add synonyms for them

Tags: support, retag-request

I had edited in a couple of these before [this post](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/63/retag-request-sql-server-tags-on-sf) was migrated from Meta SO to Meta SF, but now there's an additional tag representing the same thing.

Here are the tags involved:

`[sqlprofiler]` (2)
`[sql-profiler]` (5) (yes, all of these are for SQL Server)
`[sqlserverprofiler]` (4)

I recommend retagging all of them to use `[sql-server-profiler]` (which I just created because I had to ask a question), and adding tag synonyms for the tags listed above.

I'd do these myself, but I don't have enough rep here yet.

Comment: I see Zoredache has made the synonym requests. Time to start voting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't create the [sqlprofiler] synonym I had retagged all the question to the new tag, but forgotten I had to leave one to create the synonym.  Everything is retagged though now and the other synonyms are created.  So aside from that one thing this is status-complete.

https://serverfault.com/tags/sql-server-profiler/synonyms

Comment: Go Vote People!

Comment: Done gone in an' voted.